# Add and update child arrays value in Mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to add value in array of the following json structure in mongo db collection "Scdtls".
I need to add  value only where `"Type": "Fees"` and `"IsCurrentVersion": true`.

```json
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60e71243b484cf3ec22a6845"),
    "Item": "School",
    "Text": "School Details",
    "Types": [
      {
        "Type": "Library",
        "Values": [
          {
            "IsCurrentVersion": false,
            "KeyWords": [
              {
                "_id": ObjectId("611a4f113800d6af3fc4814f"),
                "Value": "Physics"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Type": "Fees",
        "Values": [
          {
            "IsCurrentVersion": false,
            "KeyWords": [
              {
                "_id": ObjectId("611a4f113800d6af3fc4814f"),
                "Value": "Admission"
              },
              {
                "_id": ObjectId("611a4f113800d6af3fc4814k"),
                "Value": "Canteen"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "IsCurrentVersion": true,
            "KeyWords": [
              {
                "_id": ObjectId("611a4f113800d6af3fc4814g"),
                "Value": "Tution"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is how I am trying

```js
db.Scdtls.update({
  "Item": "School",
  "Types.Type": "Fees",
  "Types.Values.IsCurrentVersion": true
},
{
  "$push": {
    "Types.1.Values.$[].KeyWords": {
      "_id": ObjectId(),
      "Value": "Sports"
    }
  }
})
```

But it is also adding `"Value": "Sports"` in `"Type" : "Fees"` where `"IsCurrentVersion": false`.
Not able to understand the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do the update you want using `"arrayFilters"`, like this:

```js
db.Scdtls.update({
  "Item": "School",
  "Types.Type": "Fees",
  "Types.Values.IsCurrentVersion": true
},
{
  "$push": {
    "Types.$[x].Values.$[y].KeyWords": {
      "_id": ObjectId("deadbeafcafebabec0deface"),
      "Value": "Sports"
    }
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    { "x.Type": "Fees" },
    { "y.IsCurrentVersion": true }
  ]
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iQmngjed8bb).